# How can I add a vertical scrollbar to a gridview?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview

The problem was that I had a setEnabled in my code. Sorry. I already fix this

I want that my gridview with height = 70dp is scrollable vertically.

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/list_label"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:numColumns="2"
    />
```

Anybody can help me with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gridView1"
android:numColumns="2"
android:gravity="center"
android:columnWidth="70dp"
android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:scrollbars="horizontal"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</GridView>
```

Comment: height = 70dp, you are changing the columns width right?

Comment: I want that my gridview has height = 70dp . How I need this
android:columnWidth="70dp"???

Comment: exactly, android:columnWidth="100dp"

Answer (score 2):

Try to use:

```
android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

For vertical scrollbar

Answer (score 1):

```
gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.rvProduit1); 
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(gridView,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
 android:scrollbars="horizontal"
```

Comment: This didn't help. I want scrollable vertically

Answer (score 0):

This will work. Use this on .java file.

```
gridView = (GridView)findViewById(R.id.list_label); 
ViewCompat.setNestedScrollingEnabled(gridView,true);
```