# I can't set Horitonzal scrollbar in gridview in android

Tags: android

**this is my code ,
i want visiable horitonzal  scrollbar in gridview , so i tried to fix it , my gridview have 1row and 3 Columns , icant use vertical scroll because content page have scroll**

```
    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
            android:background="@android:drawable/dialog_holo_light_frame">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="طرح های پیشنهادی"
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="5dp"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:textColor="#cc0066"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <GridView
                android:id="@+id/gridview1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="80dp"
                android:columnWidth="90dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:scrollbars="horizontal" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </HorizontalScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can either enable nestedscrolling in xml or you can enclose your gridview inside a nestedScrollView . Try that , if that's not working let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add ScrollView?

[HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674341/how-to-use-scrollview-in-android) is that people already talked about that. If i didn't understand you wrong.

I adding example codes for vertical and horizontal.

[How to scroll gridview to position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757325/how-to-scroll-gridview-to-position)

[How can I add a vertical scrollbar to a gridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27863064/how-can-i-add-a-vertical-scrollbar-to-a-gridview)

Firstly, end of the LinearLayout, get rid of the slash: **/>   to   >**
Here is direct answer for your question:

Put into ScrollView:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="vertical">

    <!-- your codes here -->    

</ScrollView>
```

For horizontal:

```
<HorizontalScrollView>
        <ScrollView>
            <!-- your codes here -->
        </ScrollView>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```